# two programs with same code : floating point overflow

Tags: c++, c, loops, floating-point, initialization

I'm using DEV c++.
and just faced a very weird problem.

First here I copy the code of  my programs which is running fine.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

#define f(x) 0.2027*sqrt(1-x*x)

int main()
{
    int k=0;   //<----the change is here 
    float x,y,c,z;

    c=0.6366198;
    do {

        x=2*(rand()/(float)RAND_MAX)-1;                          

        z=rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
        y=y*2*c;

        if (y<=f(x)) {
            printf("%f\t",x);
            k=k+1;
        }
    } while(k<=100);         // <--the change is here 

    getchar();
}
```

Here if I change the while condition slightly to make the program a little more generic, in DEVc++ nothing's happening. I see only a 'blank page';

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

#define f(x) 0.2027*sqrt(1-x*x)

int main()
{
    int k=0,t=100;   //<----the change is here 
    float x,y,c,z;

    c=0.6366198;

    do {
        x=2*(rand()/(float)RAND_MAX)-1;                          

        z=rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;
        y=y*2*c;

        if (y<=f(x)) {
            printf("%f\t",x);
            k=k+1;
        }
    } while(k<=t);         // <--the change is here 

    getchar();
}
```

In turboc++ too same thing's happening. Just instead of showing a blank page like Devc++, it's showing floating point overflow. Why ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I can see, in your code

```
 y=y*2*c;
```

`y` is used uninitialized. Being an automatic local variable, the initial value is indeterminate. So, both of your codes invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

To quote the standard, chapter §6.7.9, *Initialization*

> If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is
>   indeterminate. [...]

and, for undefined behavior, annex §J.2

> The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is
>   indeterminate

You need to initialize your automatic local variables, like

```
float x = 1, y = 2, c = 3, z = 4;  //values are for example purpose
```

and so on.

***Moral of the story: Please turn on the compiler warnings and pay heed to them.***

Comment: thanks, but why then the first program was running ? i never initialize a variable in this way . 
i only write 
float : x, y , z;
but yea, @sourav ghosh, now the second program is running fine. but still, if you can solve my query !

Comment: @NathanOliver That was just an example, but I see your point. Edited and added a note to clear confusions. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

In both cases, `y` is being used without initialisation:

```
float x,y,c,z;
y=y*2*c;
```

This causes undefined behavior, and the compiler should warn about that (so make sure warnings are on and preferably at the highest level).

Comment: *Also, int main() needs to return a value.* No it doesn't.  If the end of main is reached before a return statement than an implicit `return 0;` is used.

Comment: @NathanOliver just to add, `Also, int main() needs to return a value.` and it does. In case you don't give one, an implicit 0 will be returned. :)

Comment: @NathanOliver - You're right, got a warning here, but compiler was still set to C++. Updated, thanks.

Comment: @SouravGhosh I was reading it as they were saying the return statement was needed and I wanted to say that is actually not needed.

Comment: @NathanOliver, @SouravGhosh - The return value is required for C89/C90 though. I think it's good practice to include it, especially if the closing `}` is reachable.

Comment: @IanAbbott that is debatable.  I am not sure why having to write `return 0;` at then end of main is needed when it can be done implicitly.  As far as the requirement this is taged with `c` so `c11` is the standard in which the question should be answered with.